# Understanding the meaning of "sigma finite measures"

Tags: probability, integration, measure-theory

I am reading about a specific Probability Distribution Function called the Tweedie Probability Distribution:

[image]

In the above Probability Distribution, a term "v-lambda" appears and is said to be a "sigma-finite measure". I tried to read the corresponding Wikipedia page on "sigma-finite measures" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-finite_measure) - but this topic appears to be too advanced for me to understand.

In short, can someone please explain the "v-lambda" term in the above integral? Is the "v-lambda" term simply a "placeholder" term? Or does "v-lambda" actually refer to some "physically calculable term"?

Can someone please help me understand this?

Thank you!

**References:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distribution

Comment: What do you mean by integrating for "observed values of Y"? The formula for $P_{\theta,\sigma^2}(Y\in A)$ is purely theoretical and describes the Tweedie distribution.

Comment: @ jakobdt: thank you for your reply! i removed that line.

Comment: A measure space is $\sigma$-finite if the space is a countable union of sets of finite measure.

Answer (score 1):

A measure is called $\sigma$ - finite, if the measure space is a countable union of sets of finite measure (wrt to this measure). Take for example the reals with the Lesbesgue - measure: This measure (or this measure space) is $\sigma$ - finite, because you can write: $\mathbb R = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} [-n,n]$, where all the sets $[-n,n]$ have finite measure $2n < \infty$.

In the Integral, $\nu_\lambda$ is just such an measure for the underlying measure space (i think the reals, but i'm not familiar with this distribution).

Comment: @ Frederik: Thank you for your answer! If you tried to integrate this integral over some range of "Y" - could you just "ignore" the "v-lambda" term? thank you!

Comment: @stats555 The $\nu_\lambda$ can absolutely *not* be ignored. You integrate wrt. this measure so it is very significant.

Comment: @ Jakobdt: thank you for your reply! I have looked online but I just can't seem to find some reference that explains how this integral is "numerically approximated" for some range of "Y" in the real world.

Comment: No, you can't just ignore it, you have to compute the integral wrt $\nu_\lambda$. As I said, i'm not familiar with the tweedie distributions, but it seems like this measure can be seen as some kind of parameter: Choose a differnt $\nu_\lambda$ and get a different distribution. Yould choose $\nu_\lambda$ to be the Lesbesgue measure, for example.

Comment: For explicit calculatiuon: If you had a lesbesque density function for $\nu_\lambda$, you could use this to compute the integral (analytically or numerically).

Comment: @stats555 It would at least require identification of $\nu_\lambda$. As Frederik writes, identifying a density wrt. the Lebesgue (or counting) measure would be ideal. However, the stated formula for $P_{\theta,\sigma^2}(Y\in A)$ may not be the easiest to work with if you want to actually compute the value of the integral. The distribution of $Y$ might have a density wrt. the Lebesgue or counting measure, which would make the computation easier.